# MS Access Form Filter Issue

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I am having a hard time trying to solve this issue. I have a form that applies a filter to filter out the records of a corresponding engineer. So, if I put *steve*, I will only see steve's records.

I have right now up to 938 records and this is how I found out about the problem. The record 938 is from steve, but when I filter out the form by his name only I see records up to 836 one is steve's records and all other records from steve after 836 are not shown.

this is the code I'm using

```
    if Name_Filter.Value = "Steve" Then
    Me.FilterOn = True 
    RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast 'Here it shoud go to record 938 but only shows up to 836'
    Lastrcrd = CurrentRecord 'Here it should make record 938 the last record, but it makes record 836 the last' end if
```

Hope you can help what am i doing wrong.

Comment: What is your order by? Go to last depends on record order

Comment: according it depend on the ID tab an it goes ascending starting from 1 and up

Comment: Do you see all 938 records if there's no filter?

Comment: yes, if i remove the filter, i cans see all 938 records in the form and scroll between them back and forth.. the problem gets when i filter. i cannot go above 836, but i can scroll back freely

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes little sense. It should read:

```
Me.Filter = "Name_Filter = 'Steve'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Then it might be:

```
If Me!Name_Filter.Value = "Steve" Then
    Me.Filter = "NameField = 'Steve'"
    Me.FilterOn = True 
Else
    Me.FilterOn = False
End If
```

Comment: oh that's because name_filter is a dropdown box with all the names i don't know if that clears the question

Comment: nope, it is still showing up to record 836... and not 938 :( if i attach my file, do you think it could help?

Comment: Yes, but something else is going on.